# flutter_flavorizr, Different build configurations - launch icon (at release apk)

Tags: android, flutter, android-flavors

I am using flutter_flavorizr. I have set up dev/prod flavors and everything works perfectly with the command "flutter run". However, when I built the apk with the command "flutter build apk --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart", the app icon did not apply! Can I make the app icon apply even in the release build?